# Python_grouping multidimensional list

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, python-2.5

I have an example multidimensional list:

```
    example_list=[
        ["a","b","c", 2,4,5,7],
        ["e","f","g",0,0,1,5],
        ["e","f","g", 1,4,5,7],
        ["a","b","c", 3,2,5,7]
    ]
```

How is it possible to put them in groups like this:

```
out_list=[
         [["a","b","c", 2,4,5,7],
           ["a","b","c",3,2,5,7]
         ],
         [["e","f","g", 0,0,1,5],
          ["e","f","g", 1,4,5,7]
         ]
 ]
```

I have tried this:

```
example_list=[["a","b","c", 2,4,5,7],["e","f","g", 0,0,1,5],["e","f","g",1,4,5,7],["a","b","c", 3,2,5,7]]
unique=[]
index=0
for i in range(len(example_list)):
    newlist=[]
    if example_list[i][:3]==example_list[index][:3]:
        newlist.append(example_list[i])
    index=index+1
    unique.append(newlist)            
print unique
```

My results is this:

[[['a', 'b', 'c', 2, 4, 5, 7]], [['e', 'f', 'g',0, 0, 1, 5]], [['e', 'f', 'g', 1, 4, 5, 7]], [['a', 'b', 'c', 3, 2, 5,7]]]

I could not figure it out.

Comment: is the grouping depending on the three first elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the grouping is decided by the first three elements in each list following code will do what you're asking for:

```
from collections import defaultdict

example_list=[["a","b","c", 2,4,5,7],["e","f","g",0,0,1,5],["e","f","g", 1,4,5,7],["a","b","c", 3,2,5,7]]
d = defaultdict(list)
for l in example_list:
    d[tuple(l[:3])].append(l)

print d.values() # [[['a', 'b', 'c', 2, 4, 5, 7], ['a', 'b', 'c', 3, 2, 5, 7]], ...]
```

This will use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to generate a dictionary where keys are the first three elements and values are list of lists which start with those elements.

Answer (score 0):

First sort the list simply using `sorted()`, providing a `lambda` function as key.

```
>>> a = sorted(example_list, key=lambda x:x[:3])
[['a', 'b', 'c', 2, 4, 5, 7], ['a', 'b', 'c', 3, 2, 5, 7], ['e', 'f', 'g', 0, 0, 1, 5], ['e', 'f', 'g', 1, 4, 5, 7]]
```

And then use [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) on the sorted list:

```
>>> [list(v) for k, v in groupby(a, lambda x:x[:3])]
[
    [['a', 'b', 'c', 2, 4, 5, 7], ['a', 'b', 'c', 3, 2, 5, 7]], 
    [['e', 'f', 'g', 0, 0, 1, 5], ['e', 'f', 'g', 1, 4, 5, 7]]
]
```